# morphtoMany not using specified morph key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

So, I have an events table, where users can 'go' or be 'interested', and many users can go. (For this example, we'll just use it on the Events class.

So, I am specifying the morph like so:

```
/**
 * Get the user's events they're interested in
 *
 * @return builder
 */
public function interested($class = __CLASS__)
{
    return $this->morphToMany($class, 'owner', EventParticipants::table)
        ->wherePivot('status', '=', EventParticipants::INTERESTED)
        ->withPivot('owner_type', 'status', 'created_at');
}
```

Which is a trait inside my users model.

What they represent:

```
$class = "App\Modules\Events\Entities\Events"
'owner' = the key I want to use, because my DB has owner_id and owner_type
EventParticipants::table = 'event_participants'
EventParticipants::INTERESTED = "interested"
```

I can have multiple statuses (going, interested..) My database structure is like so:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('event_participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');            
        $table->integer('owner_id');
        $table->string('owner_type');
        $table->string('status')->default('pending')->comment('pending/going/interested');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And my example data:

```
INSERT INTO `social`.`event_participants` 
    (`id`, 
    `user_id`, 
    `owner_type`, 
    `owner_id`, 
    `status`, 
    `created_at`, 
    `updated_at`) 
VALUES      
    ('14', 
    '9', 
    'App\\Modules\\Events\\Entities\\Events', 
    '1', 
    '2', 
    '2018-01-27 14:19:03', 
    '2018-01-27 14:19:03');
```

But the morph trait, is not using my specified `owner` key as seen in the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'event_participants.events_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select
>   `events`.*, `event_participants`.`owner_id` as `pivot_owner_id`,
>   `event_participants`.`events_id` as `pivot_events_id`,
>   `event_participants`.`owner_type` as `pivot_owner_type`,
>   `event_participants`.`status` as `pivot_status`,
>   `event_participants`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at` from `events`
>   inner join `event_participants` on `events`.`id` =
>   `event_participants`.`events_id` where `event_participants`.`owner_id`
>   = 9 and `event_participants`.`owner_type` = App\Modules\Account\Entities\User and `event_participants`.`status` =
>   2)

From the Laravel documentation it specifies the class to morph, the key, and the table (optional)

**relationships**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

how come my code isn't abiding by he rules? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was using `morphToMany`, which was morphingTo, rather than `morphedByMany`

I fixed my issue by using the following:

**Before:**

```
/**
 * Get the user's events they're interested in
 *
 * @return builder
 */
public function interested($class = __CLASS__)
{
    return $this->morphToMany($class, 'owner', EventParticipants::table)
        ->wherePivot('status', '=', EventParticipants::INTERESTED)
        ->withPivot('owner_type', 'status', 'created_at');
}
```

**After:**

```
/**
 * Get the user's events they're interested in
 *
 * @return builder
 */
public function interested($class = __CLASS__)
{
    return $this->morphedByMany($class, 'owner', EventParticipants::table)
        ->wherePivot('status', '=', EventParticipants::INTERESTED)
        ->withPivot('owner_type', 'status', 'created_at');
}
```